# Sinatra App with multiple users

Tags: ruby, sinatra

What is the easiest way to allow for multiple users in a Sinatra web app. I've previously used an authorization class that allows for one username and password, but what if I want to allow users to sign up for a simple web app and allow them all their own login credentials?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If HTTP basic auth is sufficient I'd recommend defining two methods like this:

```
helpers do

  def protected!
    unless authorized?
      response["WWW-Authenticate"] = 'Basic realm="Protected Area"'
      throw(:halt, [401, "Not authorized\n"])
    end
  end

  def authorized?
    @auth ||=  Rack::Auth::Basic::Request.new(request.env)
    if @auth.provided? && @auth.basic? && @auth.credentials
      username,password = @auth.credentials
      # verify credentials are correct
    end
  end

end
```

Call `protected!` from any action that should be protected (or use a `before` block to protect everything). I leave the credential verification to you since I don't know how you're storing user account information.

Answer (score 0):

The [sinatra-authentication](https://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication) gem looks like an easy and powerful solution for adding users, authentication and permissions to sinatra apps.